# org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: sourceKey is not a valid field name

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to set up the Debezium MongoDB Kafka connector

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{
      "name": "my-connector",
      "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
        "mongodb.connection.string": "mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0",
        "topic.prefix": "prefix",
        "collection.include.list": "database.Collection",
        "snapshot.mode": "never",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState",
        "transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "source.ts_ms",
        }
    }';
```

Every time I insert my document into the database I get

```
    ~$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8083/connectors/activation-connector/status
    {
  "name": "activation-connector",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "127.0.1.1:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "FAILED",
      "worker_id": "127.0.1.1:8083",
      "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:230)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:391)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.execute(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:359)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:257)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.run(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:75)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:177)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: sourceKey is not a valid field name\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.lookupField(Struct.java:254)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.put(Struct.java:202)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertFieldValue(MongoDataConverter.java:216)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertFieldValue(MongoDataConverter.java:267)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.lambda$convertFieldValue$0(MongoDataConverter.java:191)\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)\n\tat java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1092)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertFieldValue(MongoDataConverter.java:183)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertFieldValue(MongoDataConverter.java:267)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.lambda$convertFieldValue$0(MongoDataConverter.java:191)\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)\n\tat java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1092)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertFieldValue(MongoDataConverter.java:183)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertRecord(MongoDataConverter.java:62)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState.newRecord(ExtractNewDocumentState.java:278)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState.apply(ExtractNewDocumentState.java:239)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:214)\n\t... 13 more\n"
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

Here's the stack trace

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:230)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:391)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.execute(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:359)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:257)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.run(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:75)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: sourceKey is not a valid field name
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.lookupField(Struct.java:254)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.put(Struct.java:202)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertFieldValue(MongoDataConverter.java:216)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertFieldValue(MongoDataConverter.java:267)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.lambda$convertFieldValue$0(MongoDataConverter.java:191)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1092)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertFieldValue(MongoDataConverter.java:183)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertFieldValue(MongoDataConverter.java:267)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.lambda$convertFieldValue$0(MongoDataConverter.java:191)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1092)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertFieldValue(MongoDataConverter.java:183)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.MongoDataConverter.convertRecord(MongoDataConverter.java:62)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState.newRecord(ExtractNewDocumentState.java:278)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState.apply(ExtractNewDocumentState.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:214)
    ... 13 more

Stack trace made readable by https://TidyTrace.com
```

My document does contain the field "sourceKey", (nested) in multiple place. Could you help me determine why?